# How to change you email, last_name, birthday in facebook profile, from android app?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to edit my profile information in Facebook. Make POST request.

Update email, last_name, birhtday;

But more of examples, and questions in stackoverflow about GET requests.
So i decided to create this ask post.

As for me, i found only this example:

```
final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("link", Utility.getUriString(linkContent.getContentUrl()));
    parameters.putString("picture", Utility.getUriString(linkContent.getImageUrl()));
    parameters.putString("name", linkContent.getContentTitle());
    parameters.putString("description", linkContent.getContentDescription());
    parameters.putString("ref", linkContent.getRef());
    new GraphRequest(
            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
            "/me/feed",
            parameters,
            HttpMethod.POST,
            requestCallback).executeAsync();
}
```

and some post from [Facebook doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)

Maby You meet more examples and info, some links
 How  to change you email, last_name, birthday in facebook profile,  from android app?

Comment: You can't. You need to manually use the Facebook app

Comment: ok. I understand ,because is a sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a post in the endpoint: /{user_id}

I am not sure if you can change birthday and email. That is a sensitive information.

You can send this parameters to do an update.

```
final Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("firstname", "Robert");
parameters.putString("lastname", "Smith");

/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id}",
    parameters,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

For more information see update section in the documentation in your link.